# Magento 2 How can I call Owl Carousel Slider in a html file?

Tags: magento2.3

I need to call the owl carousel slider in a html file in magento 2.

```
app/code/Alps/Deliveryshipping/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-list.html
```

Owl slider code

```
<div id="checkout-slider-owl" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
          <h4>1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h4>2</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h4>3</h4>
        </div>
 </div>
<script>
require([
        'jquery',
        'owlcarousel'
    ],function() {
  jQuery("#checkout-slider-owl").owlCarousel({
      navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      navigation: true,
      items : 1, 
      responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            991:{
                items:1
            },
            1024:{
                items:1
            }
        }
 
  });
});
</script>
```

I have placed Owl slider js in

```
app/design/frontend/pakage_name/theme_name/default/web/js
```

I have called owl slider js in require.js

```
/**
 *  This is used for slider
 */
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'owlcarousel': "js/owl.carousel.min",
        },   
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

but it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to created one `requirejs-config.js` file inside your theme like,

First Add `owlcarousel.js` file inside,

```
app/design/frontend/pakage_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/web/js
```

Add your css inside,

```
app/design/frontend/pakage_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/web/css
```

call css inside your tempalte file using,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Catalog::css/owlcarousel.css')?>">
```

Now create `requirejs-config.js` file

```
Magento_Catalog/requirejs-config.js
```

Define your slider,

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'owlcarousel': "Magento_Catalog/js/owlcarousel"
        },   
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can use owlcarousel under any phtml file,

```
<div id="owlslider" class="products list items product-items">
   <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
     <li>4</li>
     <li>5</li>       
  </ul>
</div>
    <script>
    (function  () {
        require(["jquery","owlcarousel"],function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#owlslider").owlCarousel({
                    navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
                    autoPlay: false, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds 
                    items : 5
                });
            });
        });
    })();
    </script>
```

Remove `pub/static` folder content and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` command flush cache